# Clickhouse Array Field - Check if ANY of the items meets condition

Tags: sql, clickhouse

In my **Clickhouse** server, I have a table with an **Array of Integers** field:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  ...
  my_array_field Array(UInt32),
  ...

)
```

Pretty simple definition.

But now I want to filter the records matching a condition like this:

**Any of the itens inside my_array_field is between 5000 and 6000**

---

In **postgres** I was doing something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM unnest(my_array_field) AS my_array_field WHERE my_array_field BETWEEN 5000 AND 6000
)
```

But now I have the same challenge in clickhouse and need some help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from my_table 
where arrayExists( i -> (i > 5000 and i < 6000) , my_array_field)
```

Comment: I used your answer in my code! Thanks a lot. But in my case it was failing because the array can be empty. So I had to add:  
`WHERE notEmpty(my_array_field)  AND arrayExists(x ->...`

If you could add that to your answer, that would be even more awesome.

Comment: ???? it's impossible. arrayExists returns 0 for emtpy arrays. `notEmpty(my_array_field)  AND` has no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [arrayJoin](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/array-join/#functions_arrayjoin) function:

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    arrayJoin(my_array_field) AS val
FROM my_table
WHERE val BETWEEN 5000 AND 6000
```

Look for details [ARRAY JOIN Clause](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/array-join/).

---

If it experienced some performance issues consider adding two extra columns to store *max* and *min* values in array:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  ...
  my_array_field Array(UInt32),
  UInt32 min_my_array_field,
  UInt32 max_my_array_field,
  ...
)

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES (.., arr, arrayMin(arr), arrayMax(arr), ..)
```

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    arrayJoin(my_array_field) AS val
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM my_table
    WHERE (min_my_array_field <= 6000) AND (max_my_array_field >= 5000)
)
WHERE val BETWEEN 5000 AND 6000
```

---

Look at [skipping indexes](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/#table_engine-mergetree-data_skipping-indexes) : for example *bloom_filter* supports Array-type.